# Change image in JLabel based on which button the cursor is hovering over?

Tags: java, image, swing, icons, jbutton

I have created a Swing interface where I want an icon to appear in a `JLabel` when the cursor is hovered over a button. The icon will change based in which button the cursor hovers over.

Here is the coding I am using at the moment:

```
public void iconchange()
    {
        if(btnPlay.isRolloverEnabled() == true)
        {
            lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/Play-icon.png"));
        }
    }
```

I know the coding above is wrong, so what can I do to achieve the feature I mentioned above?

Comment: Note: no need to mention your IDE, since this is done using Java, not an IDE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use a `ChangeListener` on the `JButton`'s `ButtonModel` to monitor changes to the models state, update your UI based on the state of the model, for example...

```
public class ChangeHandler implements ChangeListener {

    private JLabel label;
    private Icon armedIcon;

    public ChangeHandler(JLabel label, Icon armedIcon) {
        this.armedIcon = armedIcon;
        this.label = label;
    }

    @Override
    public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
        ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
        if (model.isRollover()) {
            label.setIcon(armedIcon);
        } else {
            label.setIcon(null);
        }
    }

}
```

This will update the supplied `JLabel`, changing it's `icon` to the specified `icon` when the `ButtonModel` it's attached to is in the `rollOver` state

This could be used something like this...

[image: Rollover]

```
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.ButtonModel;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeEvent;
import javax.swing.event.ChangeListener;

public class RollOver {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new RollOver();
    }

    public RollOver() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                    ex.printStackTrace();
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JLabel label;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridwidth = GridBagConstraints.REMAINDER;
            // I'm doing this, because I don't have blank icon of 128x128 and my
            // icons are both 128x128
            label = new JLabel() {
                @Override
                public Dimension getPreferredSize() {
                    return new Dimension(128, 128);
                }
            };
            add(label, gbc);
            try {
                JButton btn = new JButton("Bunnies");
                btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeHandler(label, new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Bunny.png")))));
                add(btn);
                btn = new JButton("Zomnies");
                btn.getModel().addChangeListener(new ChangeHandler(label, new ImageIcon(ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("/Zombi.png")))));
                add(btn);
            } catch (IOException exp) {
                exp.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        public class ChangeHandler implements ChangeListener {

            private JLabel label;
            private Icon armedIcon;

            public ChangeHandler(JLabel label, Icon armedIcon) {
                this.armedIcon = armedIcon;
                this.label = label;
            }

            @Override
            public void stateChanged(ChangeEvent e) {
                ButtonModel model = (ButtonModel) e.getSource();
                if (model.isRollover()) {
                    label.setIcon(armedIcon);
                } else {
                    label.setIcon(null);
                }
            }

        }

    }

}
```

Take a closer look at [How to Use Buttons, Check Boxes, and Radio Buttons](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/button.html) for more details

Comment: Can this be implemented with a Swing GUI? When I entered the coding you supplied, a lot of lines were underlined as errors? I already have a button placed using drag-and-drop called btnPlay. Is there no other way to implement this? The GIF you added to your answer is doing roughly what I am trying to do

Comment: *"Can this be implemented with a Swing GUI?"* - That entire example IS a Swing GUI.  Don't mix up the form designer with the API, the form designer is just a tool. *"I already have a button placed using drag-and-drop called btnPlay. Is there no other way to implement this?"* - Yes, you take the presented concept and apply it to your code. `btn.getModel().addChangeListener` is all you really need in your code to get started (and the `ChangeListener` implementation)

Comment: The form designer can only do so much, at some point, you're going to need to get your hands dirty with some code, the sooner the better. The form designer is crutch you can do without

Comment: I took the `btn.getModel().addChangeListener` line but it still gives me errors, mainly with my button and label

Comment: Since you have all the code, I'm not entirely sure what you expect me to do?  Make sure you've renamed `btn` to what ever you've named your button.  Some thing goes for `label`

Comment: I did name the `btn` and `label` to what I have actually named it too in my app but the error but for some reason the class is not picking them up. The `ChangeHandler` is also underlined as having an error, and when I implement the `ChangeHandler` class just about everything in there is underlined as errors.

Comment: Well, underlying could mean lots of things, what is the actual error?  Did you import the `ChangeListener`?  Did you place the `ChangeHandler` in the right context?  Again, no code, no idea

Comment: Yes I did the imports and everything. The error states it cannot find the symbol of the labels and buttons. So it seems like the class just doesn't want to pick up the objects

Answer (score 2):

Add an MouseListener to btnPlay, and use the mouse exit and enter methods

```
btnPlay.addMouseListener(new java.awt.event.MouseAdapter() {
    public void mouseEntered(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        lblIcon.setIcon(new ImageIcon("Images/Play-icon.png"));
    }

    public void mouseExited(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
        //I assume you want to remove or change the icon afterward
    }
});
```

Comment: Can this be implemented with a Swing GUI? When I entered the coding you supplied, a lot of lines were underlined as errors? I already have a button placed using drag-and-drop called btnPlay. Is there no other way to implement this?